# How do I do this without eval()

Tags: php, eval, apc

Following works, however I am wondering.
Is there a way of doing this without using eval?

```
$i = file_get_contents('/var/www/php/func/whois.php');
apc_store('whois', $i) ;
$w = apc_fetch('whois');
eval( " ?> $w <?php ");
echo whois('exsample.net');
```

I wish I could store that, evaluate by php interpreter, as executable; but that isn't going to happen easily.

Comment: Have you tried including whois.php instead of just getting the contents?

Comment: Can we please have some more of the code surrounding the issue? I can't see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway? It's still no more efficient (and possible less) than just `include`ing the file when you want to use it - you are only caching the disk read of the original file, which in reality is not going to achieve anything useful.

Comment: What is there in your `whois.php` file exactly? A function declaration?

Comment: you can find the implementation here: http://wiki.robotamer.com/linux/php/robotamer/loadf

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seamed to be a great idea at the time but after learning more about how APC works, I found out that this is all already build in.